# Shell script to Send mail if Linux Server is down

Tags: shell, scripting, email, shutdown, ping

I want to create a shell script in Linux to send an email if the Server is down.

Let's say I have Server 1 ..... Server 10.

I want to ping all Servers from Server 1 and send a mail to me if the server is down. Can someone please help me with this request.

Comment: It is assumed that you present some work you did and where you fail. Anything so far? A few hints: 1) for-loops 2) ping with timeout 3) checking exit status of a command 4) run command based on exit status of previous commands. Kindly try to do some research on these topics. Idea: "for each server ping. ping failed => send mail". Note that ping is not 100% secure when detecting the server status.

Comment: This Stackexchange is not a script-writing service. Please show us what you have tried, and where specifically you've come unstuck. Remember there's https://shellcheck.net/ for checking syntax errors

Comment: For checking the status, `nmap` is an alternative to `ping` and is more versatile, though also more complex to use. However, only use it if you own those servers or you have permission to analyze them with `nmap`, since the use of this tool is often interpreted as an attempt to break in.

Comment: `ping` is not a way to find out if a server is down or not. Use proper troubleshooting tools, that depend on the service you are trying to monitor on those servers. Also are you doing this to learn? Because if not, you are just reinventing plethora of tools that exist already and do things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Install a network monitor like Zabbix or PRTG. They're much more robust in detecting when something is up or not and has a ton of other features.